# Logical inconsistency with [ ] conversion specifier in scanf() in C

Tags: c, format-specifiers

Please have a look at this code snippet:

```
char line1[10], line2[10];
int rtn;
rtn = scanf("%9[a]%9[^\n]", line1, line2);
printf("line1 = %s|\nline2 = %s|\n", line1, line2);
printf("rtn = %d\n", rtn);
```

Output:

```
$ gcc line.c -o line
$ ./line
abook
line1 = a|
line2 = book|
rtn = 2
$./line
book
line1 = |
line2 = �Js�|
rtn = 0
$
```

For input `abook`, `%9[a]` fails at `b` from the `book` and stores previously parsed `a`+`\0` at `line1`.
Then `%9[^\n]` parses the remaining line and stores just now parsed `book`+`\0` at `line2`.
Please note 2 points here:

1. At the time of storing the parsed input, `\0` is appended at the end of it since `%[]` is a conversion specifier for a string.
2. When `%9[a]` failed at `b`, **`scanf` didn't exit**. It simply went on scanning further input.

Now for input `book`, `%9[a]` should fail at `b` from the `book` and should store just `\0` at `line1` since here nothing was parsed. 
Then `%9[^\n]` should parse the remaining line and should store just now parsed `book`+`\0` at `line2`.

Now, let's see what exactly happened:
Here return value is 0 that means `scanf` didn't assign value to any variable. `scanf` simply exited without assigning any values. So garbage data at `line2`. And in the case of `line1` that garbage data happen to be a `NULL` character.

But this is quite strange!  Isn't it?
I mean `scanf` exits if `%[...]` fails at the very first character of input. (Even if additional conversion specifier is there in `scanf` statement.)
But if the same `%[...]` fails at any other character other than first one then `scanf` simply continues scanning the further input. (If additional conversion specifier is there of course.) It doesn't exit.

So why this inconsistency?
Why not let `scanf` statement continue scan the input (if additional conversion specifier is there of course) even if `%[...]` fails at the very first char of input? Exactly like what happens in other case.
Is there any special reason behind this inconsistency?

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1) 4.4.3
```

Comment: Since you didn't check the return value from `scanf()`, you've no idea whether it said "I failed" or not.  You can't blame it when you ignore its error returns; in the second example, it will have said '0 items scanned successfully', which means that none of the variables were set to anything useful at all.  You must **always** check the return value from `scanf()` so you know whether it did what you expected.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler- I updated the code and output to show the return value of `scanf`. And yes for case 2 the return value is 0. But this doesn't answer the question. Clearly `scanf` exited in case 2. But for case 1, return value is 2 which means `scanf` successfully assigned values to both the variables. So why this inconsistency ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 2) When `%9[a]` failed at b, `scanf` didn't exit. It simply went on scanning further input.

Yes, the `%9[a]` directive means "store *up to* 9 `'a'`s, but *at least one*"<sup>(1)</sup>, so the conversion `%9[a]` did not fail, it succeeded. It found fewer `'a'`s than it could have consumed, but that's not a failure. The input *matching* failed at the `'b'`, but the conversion succeeded.

<sup>(1)</sup> Specified in 7.21.6.2 (12) where the conversions are described:

> `[`   Matches a **nonempty sequence** of characters from a set of expected characters (the *scanset*).

> Now for input book, `%9[a]` should fail at b from the book and should store just `'\0'` at line1 since here nothing was parsed. Then `%9[^\n]` should parse the remaining line and should store just now parsed `book+\0` at line2.

No. It is supposed to exit when a conversion fails. The first conversion `%9[a]` failed, so `scanf` is supposed to stop and return 0, since no conversion succeeded.

Always check the return value of `scanf`.

That is specified (for `fscanf`, but `scanf` is equivalent to `fscanf` with `stdin` as input stream) in 7.21.6.2 (16):

> The `fscanf` function returns the value of the macro `EOF` if an input failure occurs
>   before the first conversion (if any) has completed. **Otherwise, the function returns the
>   number of input items assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero, in
>   the event of an early matching failure.**
>
> Here output for `line1` is nothing which is exactly what we expected. An empty string!

You can't expect anything. The arrays `line1` and `line2` aren't initialised, so when the conversion fails, their contents is still indeterminate. In this case, `line1` contained no printable character before the first 0 byte.

> But for `line2` it's garbage chars! We didn't expect this. So how did this happen ?

That's what happened to be the contents of `line2`. There were never any values assigned to the elements, so they are whatever they happened to be before the call to `scanf`.

Comment: It didn't. You can see from the output that it assigned `book` to `line2`.

Comment: @rootkea Sure, just added it.

Answer (score 1):

*Transferred from comments to the question since the response to the reply question requires more space than the comments allow.*

This comment refers to an earlier version of the code:

> Since you didn't check the return value from `scanf()`, you've no idea whether it said "I failed" or not. You can't blame it when you ignore its error returns; in the second example, it will have said '0 items scanned successfully', which means that none of the variables were set to anything useful at all. You must **always** check the return value from `scanf()` so you know whether it did what you expected.

The reply question is:

> I updated the code and output to show the return value of `scanf`. And yes for case 2 the return value is 0. But this doesn't answer the question. Clearly `scanf` exited in case 2. But for case 1, return value is 2 which means `scanf` successfully assigned values to both the variables. So why this inconsistency?

I don't see any inconsistency.  The [`fscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fscanf.html) specification (copied from ISO/IEC 9899:2011, but the URL links to POSIX rather than the C standard) says:

> ¶3 [...] Each conversion specification is introduced by the character `%`.
>   After the `%`, the following appear in sequence:
>
> — An optional assignment-suppressing character *.
>   — An optional decimal integer greater than zero that specifies the maximum field width
>   (in characters).
>   — An optional *length modifier* that specifies the size of the receiving object.
>   — A *conversion specifier* character that specifies the type of conversion to be applied.

Later, it says:

> ¶8 [...] Input white-space characters (as specified by the `isspace` function) are skipped, unless
>   the specification includes a `[`, `c`, or `n` specifier.<sup>284)</sup>
>
> ¶9 An input item is read from the stream, unless the specification includes an `n` specifier. An
>   input item is defined as the longest sequence of input characters which does not exceed
>   any specified field width and which is, or is a prefix of, a matching input sequence.<sup>285)</sup>
>   The first character, if any, after the input item remains unread. ***If the length of the input
>   item is zero, the execution of the directive fails***; this condition is a matching failure unless
>   end-of-file, an encoding error, or a read error prevented input from the stream, in which
>   case it is an input failure.
>
> ¶12 [...]
>
> `[` Matches a ***nonempty*** sequence of characters from a set of expected characters
>   (the scanset).<sup>286)</sup>

*[Bold italic emphasis added.  I've left the footnote references in place, but the contents of the footnotes are not material to the discussion so I've omitted them.]*

So, the behaviour you are seeing is exactly what the standard demands.  When `%9[a]` is applied to the string `abook`, there is a sequence of one `a` which matches the `%9[a]` conversion specification, so the directive is successful, and the scan continues with `book`.  When `%9[a]` is applied to the string `book`, there are zero characters matching the item, so the execution of the directive fails and it is a matching error and since it is the first conversion specification, the return value of 0 is correct.

Note that the length specifies a maximum field width, so the `9` in `%9[a]` means 1-9 letters `a`.